# PsExec gets stuck on licence prompt when running non-interactively

Tags: windows-services, psexec, sysinternals

I have a Hudson build script which calls the SysInternals PsExec utility. Normally, when PsExec is run for the first time by a given user it pops up a dialog box asking the user to accept the licence. The build agent runs as a service and I can see that the build gets stuck at PsExec. Process Explorer shows that PsExec is running, so I strongly suspect it's displaying that same prompt, but because it's running non-interactively there is no way to accept the prompt. Is there any way to get around this silly limitation? Running on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Use the `/accepteula` command-line switch to accept the licence agreement.

Or set

```
HKCU\Software\Sysinternals\PsExec\EulaAccepted
```

to 1

Caution: if the reg key above is set to 0 (EULA was declined once) then the /accepteula will *not* work, you have to set the key to 1 manually (or delete it altogether).

Comment: Great, thank you! `/accepteula` does the trick. I wonder why it's not documented?

Comment: Thanks!  I needed to get our build server to recycle our application pools after a deployment - I wanted to use psexec to execute appcmd remotely, but it was getting stuck at the license screen.  This was perfect!

Comment: It is documented - It's right at the very top of the GUI when it first displays - I guess Mark wants you to see the EULA at least once.

Comment: They didn't add this "feature" until Microsoft bought SysInternals.

Comment: Unfortunately the `-accepteula` or `/accepteula` command-line options don't work when running Sysinternals programs from Azure's Kudu command-line.

Answer (score 3):

-accepteula flag will suppress the display of the license dialog. More options are available here: https://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html

Answer (score 0):

It's documented, but you have to use the 2003 version or higher.