# Executing .bat files using jenkins

Tags: java, batch-file, jenkins, cmd, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to run a jar file using a bat command with jenkins. and I want to popup the cmd and execute the jar file. but the problem is jenkins execute commands inside its console. Then i inserted "start" command and hoped it'll work coz it creates a separate cmd to run the jar. 
here is my bat code

```
start "window_name" java -jar myjarfile.jar
```

but when i executing using it jenkins it doesn't create a separate cmd window but it executes the jar file anyhow. it shows this line,

```
 C:\Update>start "window_name" java -jar myjarfile.jar
```

any idea how to solve this? I want to pop up a black window when executing.

Comment: start "window_name" cmd /c "java -jar myjarfile.jar"

Comment: @r3ap3r thanks. but the result is same :(

Comment: Why do you want a console to popup?  A popup would not work for the Jenkins HTTP interface anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guys, May be your solutions too will do the trick. Finally what I did is i created a socket program and executed server myself. Then scheduled jenkins to execute the client.(Server in my environment & client in jenkin's environment) When client connects to the server it executes the bat file. Now everything works fine.

Comment: Please see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602951/open-excel-on-jenkins-ci/22610664#22610664. Note about using `cmd /k` for debugging, as you will probably run into pathing issues

Answer (score 1):

The trick is figuring out in what *session* you want to start the `cmd.exe`. On a remote server (which is most often the case with Jenkins), it's not necessary straight forward. Your Remote Desktop Session is not in the same session as someone who is logged in physically at the console.

- Bring up **Windows Task Manager**
- Click the **Users** tab
- Note down the **ID** of the session of the logged in user that you want
- Download `psexec` from [Windows Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553)
- ***Edited from here downwards***
- Open elevated command prompt: type `cmd` into Start's quicksearch, right click `cmd.exe`, select `Run as Administrator`.
- Type `C:\path\to\psexec.exe -accepteula` and press enter.
- Type `C:\path\to\psexec.exe -i 1 cmd` and press enter. (If you see a command prompt appear, all is good, close it now)
- In Job configuration, configure **Execute Windows Batch command** step
  Write the following:
  `C:\path\to\psexec.exe -accepteula && C:\path\to\psexec.exe -i 1 cmd /c start C:\full\path\to\java.exe -jar myjarfile.jar`

A more detailed explanation is provided in this answer [Open Excel on Jenkins CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602951/open-excel-on-jenkins-ci/22610664#22610664)

Comment: Thanks bro. But still no change. . .

Comment: Prob is jenkins executes everything in its own environment. It can't access the current one. It asks permission to show results (to show the windows that are created by jar. . .etc)

Comment: Try adding `-s` to use Local System privileged account. Also, [accept the EULA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151034/psexec-gets-stuck-on-licence-prompt-when-running-non-interactively/5151078#5151078)

Comment: Or you can try a "service" method workaround http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/archive/2004/11/27/271063.aspx

Comment: I've seen another similar question and that got me to actually try doing it. After some trial and error, I've got a working solution (for another .exe). I've modified the answer.