# PowerShell :: How to filter worker processes list by User Name

Tags: powershell, iis-8

Basically as per screen-shot there are multiple worker processes are running on machine in IIS but we need w3wp which is running under **Sitecore User** Username.
We tried below PS script but getting blank value in **User Name** column

```
$processlist  = get-process  | where {$_.cpu -gt 5 -and $_.Name -eq 'w3wp'} |select Name, @{l="User name";e={$_.getowner().user}} | ft -AutoSize
foreach($proc in $processlist){
if($proc -eq "Sitecore User" ){
     C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\someexe.exe $proc.Id "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\output.dmp" 
     }
}
```

and finally we need to perform some action on process Id.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014536/how-to-get-iis-apppool-worker-process-id Worker processes belong to their application pools, and then you can compare pool identity to the user account you would like to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following PoSh-Script that should give you all the necessary info and more:

```
# Ensure to import the WebAdministration module
Import-Module WebAdministration

# Declare the variables
$server = "localhost"
$search = "*"

$wmiQuery=[wmisearcher]"SELECT * FROM __Namespace where NAME like 'WebAdministration' or NAME like 'MicrosoftIISv2'"
$wmiQuery.Scope.Path = "\\" + $server + "\root"
$WebNamespace = $wmiQuery.Get()

# Checking if the the server has IIS installed
if($WebNamespace -like '*WebAdministration*')
{
    "IIS  found on $server"
    $WPlist=Get-WmiObject -NameSpace 'root\WebAdministration' -class 'WorkerProcess' -ComputerName 'LocalHost'
    # Loop through the list of active IIS Worker Processes w3wp.exe and fetch the PID, AppPool Name and the startTime

    forEach ($WP in $WPlist)
    {
        if ($WP.apppoolname -like$search)
        {
           write-host "Found:""PID:"$WP.processid  "AppPool_Name:"$WP.apppoolname
           (get-process -ID $WP.processid|select starttime)
        }
    }
}
Else
{
   write-host"WARNING: IIS not detected."
}
```

Ref: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webtopics/2015/11/28/query-the-active-worker-process-information-in-iis-7-x-using-powershell/

Comment: @wp78sw
this is awesome...I got exactly what I expected...now basically I'm executing proddump.exe from this PS script and when I ran this script I got message `This is the first run of this program. You must accept EULA to continue.
Use -accepteula to accept EULA.` 
Looks like I need to accept agreement first( a kind of a Agree button click ) to proceed further how can we achieve this while running PS script

Comment: @Sukhjeevan I am glad this answer fits your needs. Feel free to accept & upvote. Nonetheless, let's stay on topic. You may want to post a new question regarding your later issue. Have you tried to add `-accepteula` or `/accepteula`? See checkhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151034/psexec-gets-stuck-on-licence-prompt-when-running-non-interactively

Comment: thanks @wp78de for your quick help....I have created a new post for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49991777/getting-error-while-using-accepteula-to-accept-eula