# Getting error while using /accepteula to accept EULA

Tags: powershell, command-line-arguments

Referring [filter worker processes list by User Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952133/powershell-how-to-filter-worker-processes-list-by-user-name/49952450?noredirect=1#comment86964120_49952450)

I'm able to retrieve expected output in above URL but stuck while using/accepteula to accept EULA
I'm getting below error message. Might be that's not correct way to accept EULA

[image]

Basically I'm executing script in PowerShell ISE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PsExec gets stuck on licence prompt when running non-interactively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151034/psexec-gets-stuck-on-licence-prompt-when-running-non-interactively)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command-line switches have to be used when calling the executable. They are bound to that application. Just entering `/accepteula` on the command line is an error because there's no context, nothing to accept the switch.

```
yourprogram.exe /accepteula
```

Comment: awesome @alroc it's worked out so in my case complete executable statement is
C:\Utilities\procdump.exe /accepteula -n 3 -s 5 -c 85 -ma <PID> "C:\Utilities\output.dmp"